# How to customize Windows Failover clustering to trigger on failure of custom window service?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, failovercluster

i'm a total newbie on windows failover clustering.

and what i want to do now is to setup the FC (failover clustering) on two win 2008 R2 server.

and right now i have my custom window service running on both machine.

But they cannot run concurrently as it will mess up the DB, thus i just want one to be available at all time (high availability).

so i'm wondering if there's any way to set the failover policy to include this custom window service that i've installed on these machines so that if this service goes down or die, then it will automatically trigger the failover to the second node.

1. is this possible?
2. or must it be done programatically?
3. and if so what is the best way?

thanks ~m

Answer (score 0):

You can configure a generic service for high availability in a failover cluster. See here for more details:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753938.aspx

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732478.aspx

Comment: cool, will test and see if this method works!